# Get Windows to copy the first file of a selection first

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, copy-paste, file-transfer

When selecting a bunch of files in Explorer, either by dragging or shift-selecting, if you copy that selection and go to paste it somewhere the Windows decides it'll copy the last file in the selection first, then copy the rest *in order*.

Seems a bit weird, and usually its fine (because, when the copy is finished, who cares?). The problem is if the copy is large, and you want to get as many done before cancelling (either due to time or storage constraints).

Say, you're copying a tv show series to your mp3 player. At time of cancellation you'll have a bunch of eps (not all), then a random final episode.

I'm pretty sure this happens with most Windows OS's but I've only have 7 to test on.
And I think it's the selecting that's the issue (not Explorer's copy, so using [TeraCopy](http://codesector.com/teracopy) wouldn't help. I'm using MTP anyway, so TeraCopy won't work) because I have a work around (I'll post it as an answer if a real solution isn't found).

I'm just wondering if there's some setting (standard/advanced or [tweak](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista)) I can affect to make it always copy in order.

[Related](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080611064111AAaxYMB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best workaround I have is;

- Make the selection any way you want. (drag, ctrl+click, shift-select)
- Hold `ctrl` and deselect then reselect the file you want to be copied first

That's it. You can still select any way you want, and it isn't too hard to get the file you want (I guess this is even *more* useful as you may want a specific file across first).
But yeah, a fix to not have to do this every time would be appreciated.

Comment: I have found that this usually works, but not always. It seems to be complicated by duplications in base names. For instance, if you have bar.doc, bar.txt, boo.txt, foo.doc, foo.txt, and mark boo.txt last, the files are copied in alphabetical order. In fact it seems they are copied in alpha order regardless of how you select them.

Answer (score 4):

after selecting your files. right click on the **first** file, (or whichever file you want to go first) to copy it first. (you might have to scroll back to the top.)

whichever file you right click on will always go first to copy, cut, (it's also very useful to) play videos, music etc.

Comment: upvote for more insight

Comment: nah it's the exact same work around as the other two; make the file you want the last selected file (which the extra insight by your answer is that right clicking can achieve this too). A straight-up answer would actually address the crux of the question *some setting I can affect to make it always copy in order*, id est, without these manual behaviours on the user's part

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have ever found is to select the last item first and go backward to the first item.